# Inserting records into the table based on the last insert

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am executing a SSIS SQL task that would execute a stored procedure and that would read records from one table and dump the records in the destination table

Following is the statement that I am using to achieve that

```
INSERT INTO dbo.GetParties 
    EXEC dbo.getParties_SSIS
```

I am trying to make the stored procedure smart enough so that when it is executed the second or n number of times it checks for the max of the destination table and fetches records based on that from the source table.

How do I handle the first time the stored procedure is executed as there would be no records in the destination table? What's is the best way of handling that?

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getParties_SSIS]
AS
    DECLARE @lastCompanyId INT 
    SELECT @lastCompanyId = MAX(companyId) FROM GetParties

    SELECT 
        c.companyId, 
        cf.identifierValue dunsId, 
        c.companyName, 
        ct.companyTypeId, ct.companyTypeName,
        cst.companyStatusTypeId, cst.companyStatusTypeName,
        si.simpleIndustryId, si.simpleIndustryDescription,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.companyId) AS position
    FROM 
        ciqcompany c 
    LEFT JOIN 
        ciqSimpleIndustry si ON si.simpleIndustryId = c.simpleIndustryId 
    LEFT JOIN 
        ciqCompanyType ct ON ct.companyTypeId = c.companyTypeId
    LEFT JOIN 
        ciqCompanyStatusType cst ON cst.companyStatusTypeId = c.companyStatusTypeId
    LEFT JOIN 
        ciqCompanyCrossRef cf ON cf.companyId = c.companyId  
                              AND cf.identifierTypeId = 6 AND cf.primaryFlag = 1
    WHERE   
        c.companyId > @lastCompanyId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve quite easily with ISNULL or COALESCE.

```
WHERE   c.companyId > ISNULL(@lastCompanyId, 0)
```

or

```
WHERE   c.companyId > COALESCE(@lastCompanyId, 0)
```

Comment: or `WHERE c.companyId > @lastCompanyId OR @lastCompanyId IS NULL`.   After all, you're assuming there are no negative numbers in companyId.  :)

Comment: @TabAlleman but that is a relatively reasonable assumption. Certainly something I should have mentioned. :)